# To Call Controller Void Method On Button Click Using AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a void method in my Controller when I click on a Button using Ajax. But when I do so nothing happens. It does not hit the Controller method.

This is my View:

```
<td>
    <span class="leftalign">
         <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Picked Output" />
    </span>
</td>
<script>
$("#myButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var rootUrl = "~/Report/";
    $.ajax({
        //url: $(this).attr("href"),
        url: rootUrl + "Picksapout/pickssap",
        success: function(){
        alert("#");  
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My Controller Void Method:

```
public class PicksapoutController : MasterController
{
    private void pickssap()        
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript will not convert your relative path to a real url.  It does;t understand `~/`.  whatever you place in the ajax url parameter needs to be something that you could place in an anchor element's href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate your url correctly using

```
url: '@Url.Action("pickssap", "Picksapout")',
```

But your method should is `private` and will never be hit. Change it to be

```
public ActionResult pickssap()
```